# hoverPause stops slider forever

Tags: jquery, slidesjs

I'm using SlidesJS (sliedejs.com) and I want the slideshow to stop when I hover on it. For that I set `hoverPause: true;` and it works. The only problem is that when I stop hovering the cursor over the slideshow it doesn't move anymore. I have to reload the page in order to make it work again. What I want obviously is that the slideshow continues to work after the cursor is not over it. I've been checking the options but nothing seems to work. Maybe somebody has a hack for it or something like that (or another slideshow plugin to recommend).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a value for the pause attribute [as suggested here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/slidesjs/3tgTAFh7exg)

```
hoverPause: true,
pause: 4000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry I didn't know there is a google group. cheers